# Simple Tictactoe program

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to implement a simple tic tac toe program, but having difficulty implementing the gaming. This is the code I have so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
click = False

class Buttons(object):

    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button1= Button(frame,text=" ",height=4,width=8,
                             command=self.moveYes)
        self.button1.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.button2= Button(frame,text=" ",height=4,width=8,
                             command=self.moveYes)
        self.button2.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.button3= Button(frame,text=" ",height=4,width=8,
                             command=self.moveYes)
        self.button3.grid(row=0,column=2)

        self.button4= Button(frame,text=" ",height=4,width=8,
                             command=self.moveYes)
        self.button4.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.button5= Button(frame,text=" ",height=4,width=8,
                             command=self.moveYes)
        self.button5.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.button6= Button(frame,text=" ",height=4,width=8,
                             command=self.moveYes)
        self.button6.grid(row=1,column=2)

        self.button7= Button(frame,text=" ",height=4,width=8,
                             command=self.moveYes)
        self.button7.grid(row=2,column=0)

        self.button8= Button(frame,text=" ",height=4,width=8,
                             command=self.moveYes)
        self.button8.grid(row=2,column=1)

        self.button9= Button(frame,text=" ",height=4,width=8,
                             command=self.moveYes)
        self.button9.grid(row=2,column=2)

    def moveYes(self):
        global click
        global buttons
        if buttons["text"] == " " and click == False:
            buttons["text"]="X"
            click= True
        elif buttons["text"] == " " and click == True:
            buttons["text"]="O"

root = Tk()
b=Buttons(root)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run this, it says:

```
global name 'buttons' is not defined
```

I guess my second method isn't correct. I don't understand how to access the buttons and compare values so that I may change the text.

Should I, for now, start with a double player format and later on move to AI?

Comment: How about you declare a global variable `buttons` as you do with `click`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl i had tried but that isn't helping either. :( could it be that my way of accessing the individual buttons using a single variable is wrong?

Comment: @momo The name `buttons` is not defined outside the `moveYes` function. That's why you're seeing that error. Typically, `global` is used to make a variable accessible *inside* a function although it was initially defined *outside* that function. Btw. you can cut back on your code repetition by defining your buttons in two `for` loops instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, whenever you find yourself repeating almost the same line or lines of code, it's a clue that you need to write some kind of loop.

Secondly, you can avoid using a global variable by passing the data as an argument to your `command` function — which will make the error you're getting go away.

In this case it's just the button that was clicked, and can be done by creating a short `lamdba` function with the button as a default argument. This has to be after the Tkinter `Button` is created, and therefore requires doing a separate `config()` call *after* its creation. Passing extra data like this is sometimes called [the extra arguments trick](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/extra-args.html) and can be extended to include other items of interest, like the row and column of the button (or even the whole list of them).

```
from Tkinter import *

class Buttons(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.buttons = []
        for row in xrange(3):
            for col in xrange(3):
                button = Button(frame, text=" ", height=4, width=8)
                button.config(command=lambda b=button: self.clicked(b))
                button.grid(row=row, column=col)
                self.buttons.append(button)

    def clicked(self, button):
        if button["text"] == " ":
            button["text"] = "X"
        else:
            button["text"] = "O"

root = Tk()
b = Buttons(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Now that the basic graphical user interface is running and you have a function being called whenever the user clicks a grid position, you can start implementing the "gaming". This could be done by adding code to the `clicked()` method that checks to see what positions are filled with what character (`"X"` or `"O"`) and responding accordingly.

I think it would be simplest to start by implementing an "AI" version first, because doing that would require the least amount of effort.

Comment: thank you for the detailed response! immensely helpful :)

Comment: You're welcome. I added a couple more suggestions to my answer. Another advantage of implementing the AI version first is that it will require you to write code than can be reused in the two player version and improve your Python and Tkinter skills before tackling the likely more complicated version. To make the code more reusable, try to avoid using global variables and pass as much data as possible via arguments to "helper" functions which don't care what the kind of players there are (human vs computer or human vs human).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are trying to assign the `global` keyword from within your function to a variable that does not exist.

There is no `buttons` variable in the main body of your file.

Comment: that didn't change much. it now says "name 'buttons' is not defined".

Comment: I didn't have a closer look at the rest of your code – you asked one specific question about one specific error message you got, which I tried to answer. It's impossible to tell what's causing the new error messages because I don't know which changes you made to your code just now. Also, this would change your original question, not really sure where you're trying to go with it. (Stackoverflow is not the right place for a continuous back-and-forth while you're programming something.)

Comment: Anyway, it looks like you're trying to access `buttons` even earlier already, so that's probably why you're now getting `name 'buttons' not defined`. You'll have to reference the global variable at the start of every function. (Or move it inside of your class.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem when you click on a button, the program needs to know which button you clicked, which is why you're trying to access some global `buttons`, there's no need for that, you can pass the button and anything else that is required into your command handler e.g. `command=lambda self.click(self.button_x)`

```
    self.button1= Button(frame,                                                    
                         height=4, width=8,
                         text=' ',
                         command=lambda: self.click(self.button1)
    )
```

And here's  the `click()` method I used in the button command above

```
def click(self, button):
    """
    Dummy logic for demo, it toggles between O and X
    """

    if button['text'] == ' ' or button['text'] == 'O':                 
        button['text'] = 'X'                                                
    else:                                                                   
        button['text'] = 'O'
```

**I've run the program, it works in the sense that the button can toggle between X and O, which demonstrates the button command facility, I'll leave the actual tic tac toe game to you.**